# tbl_regression (gtsummary )- how to display confidence interval limits for 1 - HR in correct order?

Tags: gtsummary

I calculate the effectiveness of vaccination (VE), which I get as 1 - HR from the cox model.
I use the tbl_regression function to create a table with VE and corresponding confidence intervals.

Using this code, I get the confidence intervals limits in the table in the opposite order than I would like (VE (upper CI - lower CI)):

tbl_regression(m1_cox, estimate_fun = function(x) {round(1 - exp(x) , 2)}

Is there any way to display the limits of the CI in the correct order (VE (lower CI - upper CI))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can! See example below

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(survival)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.0'

tbl <- 
  coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex, data = lung) |> 
  tbl_regression(estimate_fun = function(x) style_ratio(1 - exp(x), 2)) |> 
  modify_column_hide(ci) |>                                   # hide the current confidence interval
  modify_column_merge(pattern = "{conf.high}, {conf.low}") |> # re-construct a CI reversing the order
  modify_header(                                              # update the headers to match the new estimates
    conf.high = "**95% CI**",
    estimate = "**VE**"
  ) |> 
  modify_footnote(                                            # update the abbreviation footnotes
    estimate = "VE = Vaccine Effectiveness",
    conf.high = "CI = Confidence Interval",
    abbreviation = TRUE
  )
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2023-03-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>